# Show Images in picture edit with devexpress gridview with DevExpress.Utils or other solutions with paths combined in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I haven't been able to display the image in the picture edit probably because my code isn't correct or there's another solution or recommendation that's best.
or there is another way by combining the parent path folder and filename even though the filename is in the subfolder so that it can display the image.

```
for information
filePath1 : C:\Users\ADMIN2\Desktop\CATALOG FINAL2\ART RANDOM TAMAKA\888108(1).jpg
filePath1 : C:\Users\ADMIN2\Desktop\CATALOG FINAL2\ART RANDOM TAMAKA\888108(2).jpg
filePath2 : C:\Users\ADMIN2\Desktop\CATALOG FINAL2\CATALOG MOLFON 2015\SLONG\1908012(1).jpg
filePath2 : C:\Users\ADMIN2\Desktop\CATALOG FINAL2\CATALOG MOLFON 2015\SLONG\1908012(6).jpg
```

Thanks
jack

[Capturegridview22022022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUX97.jpg)

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable
    Dim Path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\PRODUCT2.mdb"
    Private parentpathimage As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\CATALOG FINAL2"
    Dim cn = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path
    Private Images As Hashtable = New Hashtable()
    Private Sub LoadDataGridView()
        Try
            'Dim dt = New DataTable()
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query = "select Code,Filename1,Filename2,SUBFOLDERP FROM ITEM"
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn.ToString)
                adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using
            Me.GridControl1.DataSource = dt
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadDataGridView()
    End Sub
    Private Sub GridView1_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellClick
        Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
        Dim SUBFOLDERP As String
        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "SUBFOLDERP")) Then
            SUBFOLDERP = CStr(view.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "SUBFOLDERP"))
        Else
            SUBFOLDERP = String.Empty
            If e.Column.FieldName = "Filename1" Then
                Dim Filename1 As String = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column).ToString
                Dim filePath1 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & SUBFOLDERP, Filename1, False)
                PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1)), True, False)
            Else
                If e.Column.FieldName = "Filename2" Then
                    Dim Filename2 As String = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column).ToString
                    Dim filePath2 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & SUBFOLDERP, Filename2, False)
                    PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2)), True, False)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetFocusedRowCellValue(System.String)

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable
    Dim Path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\PRODUCT2.mdb"
    Private parentpathimage As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\CATALOG FINAL2"
    Dim cn = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path
    Private Images As Hashtable = New Hashtable()
    Private Sub LoadDataGridView()
        Try
            'Dim dt = New DataTable()
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query = "select Code,Filename1,Filename2,SUBFOLDERP FROM ITEM"
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn.ToString)
                adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using
            Me.GridControl1.DataSource = dt
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadDataGridView()
    End Sub
    Private Sub GridView1_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellClick
        Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
        ***Dim SUBFOLDERP As String = view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("SUBFOLDERP").ToString***
            If e.Column.FieldName = "Filename1" Then
                Dim Filename1 As String = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column).ToString
                Dim filePath1 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & SUBFOLDERP, Filename1, False)
                PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1)), True, False)
            Else
                If e.Column.FieldName = "Filename2" Then
                    Dim Filename2 As String = view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.Column).ToString
                    Dim filePath2 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & SUBFOLDERP, Filename2, False)
                    PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2)), True, False)
                End If
            End If
    End Sub
End Class
```